# php - Bitmask "decode"

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I would like to write a function to 'decode' bit mask into original values, e.g.
We have number and text attached to it:

- **2** - Text_1
- **4** - Text_2
- **8** - Text_3
- **16** - Text_4
- **32** - Text_5

Now I'm entering number e.g. `48` (`32 + 16`) and I should get `Text_5` and `Text_4` so it's should return two numbers: `32` and `16`.
How to get this?

Comment: Have you tried to write anything yourself?

Comment: What do you exactly want as output?Can you make it more clear? Do you want  48 as `Text_5` and `Text_4` or `32` and `16`? Or Both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, this is the simplest and most "native" implementation:

```
$array = [2 => 'Text_1', 4 => 'Text_2', 8 => 'Text_3', 16 => 'Text_4', 32 => 'Text_5'];

$number = 48;

foreach ($array as $mask => $string)
{
    if ($number & $mask)
    {
        echo "$mask: $string" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: How on earth is this the accepted answer over mine below. *shakes head* (it only works for a fixed set of inputs). @Paul, if you are being graded for your answer, this is not a good one.

Comment: @lufc, you missed the point of the question. I have also some side comments about performance, but I'm here not to discuss your answer.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has some functions to help with this, primarily `decbin()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) which will convert an integer to binary. You can then break that up into an array which will be numbered by the `Text_` values from your example.

```
$input = 48;
$output = array_reverse(str_split(decbin($input)));

foreach ($output as $k => $v) {
    echo $v ? "Text_$k".PHP_EOL : "";
}
```

So `decbin(48)` would give `110000`, which you can break into the following array with `str_split()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 0
)
```

But you can see this is backwards - in binary we number the bits from right to left, not left to right. So you need to reverse it, using `array_reverse()`.

Then you have a nice array of `Text_ => active (1 or 0)` pairs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using only bit operators...

```
unmaskMe(48);

function unmaskMe(int $bitset) {
    $bitOfsset = 0;

    while ($bitset) {
        if ($bitset & (1 << $bitOfsset)) {
            echo 'Text_' .  $bitOfsset . PHP_EOL;

            $bitset &= ~(1 << $bitOfsset);
        }

        $bitOfsset++;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> Text_4
>
> Text_5